# Боковая панель на всю высоту страницы за рамками сетки bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Подскажите по разметке страницы html. Ссылка для визуализации https://wireframe.cc/NBoG1D

Центральная часть по сетке bootstrap. Боковые колонки за границами сетки. Как лучше реализовать и какая структура html наиболее оптимальная будет?

Comment: Здравствуйте! В вашем вопросе звучит что-то про боковые колонки, при этом в вашем wireframe что-то непонятное, не похожее на боковые колонки. Желаю вам, чтобы вы улучшили свой вопрос, для будущих читателей. Всего вам доброго!

Answer (score 1):

Центральную часть в div с максимальной шириной, а боковые колонки `position:absolute; rigth:0; и left:0;` соответственно. Также добавить им `z-index` необходимый.